# How to use multiple sessions per connection in a multi-threaded application?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, xms, jms-session

Suppose I have one connection `c` and many session objects `s1`, `s2` .. `sn`, each working in different threads `t1`, `t2` ... `tn`.

```
                                      c
                                      |
                -------------------------------------------------
                |          |          |                         |
             (t1,s1)    (t2,s2)    (t3,s3)      ......       (tn,sn)
```

Now suppose one of the thread `t3` wants to send a message to a particular queue `q3` and then listen to the reply asynchronously. So it does the following:

```
 1:   c.stop();

 2:   auto producer = s3.createProducer(s3.createQueue(q3));
 3:   auto text = s3.createTextMessage(message);
 4:   auto replyQueue = s3.createTemporaryQueue();
 5:   text.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);
 6:   producer.send(text);

 7:   auto consumer = s3.createConsumer(replyQueue);
 8:   consumer.setMessageListener(myListener);

 9:   c.start();
```

The reason why I called `c.stop()` in the beginning and then `c.start()` in the end, because I'm *not* sure if any of the other threads has called `start` on the connection (making **all** the sessions asynchronous — is that right?) and as per [the documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_cmesdel_async.htm):

> "If synchronous calls, such as creation of a consumer or producer, must be made on an asynchronous session, the **Connection.Stop** must be called. A session can be resumed by calling the **Connection.Start** method to start delivery of messages."

So calling `stop` in the beginning of the steps and then `start` in the end seems reasonable and thus the code seems correct (at least to me). However, when I thought about it more, I think the code is buggy, as it doesn't make sure no other threads call `start` before `t3` finishes all the steps.

So my questions are:

- Do I need to use mutex to ensure it? Or the XMS handles it automatically (which means my reasoning is wrong)?
- How to design my application so that I dont have to call `stop` and `start` everytime I want to send a messages and listen reply asynchronously?
- As per the quoted text above, I cannot call `createProducer()` and `createConsumer()` if the connection is in asynchronous mode. What are other methods I cannot call? The documentation doesn't categorise the methods in this way:

Also, the documentation doesn't say clearly what makes a session asynchronous. It says [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_cmesdel_async.htm):

> "A session is not made asynchronous by assigning a message listener to a consumer. A session becomes asynchronous only when the Connection.Start method is called."

I see two problems here:

- Calling `c.start()` makes **all** sessions asynchronous, not just one.
- If I call `c.start()` but doesn't assign any message listener to a consumer, are the session(s) still asynchronous?

It seems I've lots of questions, so it'd be great if anyone could provide me with links to the parts or sections of the documentation which explains XMS objects with such minute details.

[This](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=230852535) says,

> "According to the specification, calling stop(), close() on a Connection, setMessageListener() on a Session etc. must wait till all message processing finishes, that is till all onMessage() calls which have already been entered exit. So if anyone attempts to do that operation inside onMessage() there will be a deadlock by design."

But I'm not sure if that information is authentic, as I didn't find this info on IBM documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the KIS rule.  Why don't you use 1 connection per thread?  Hence, the code would not have to worry about conflicts between threads.

Comment: Why dont I use one connection per thread?Well, there could be this scenario: suppose the master server needs to communicate with many worker servers, so if I use one connection per thread, I might end up using N connections (N could be large enough so as to be infeasible or impractical, for some definition of *large*, 20, 30 or even more). Also, if a thread uses a connection infrequently, it seems a better strategy if this connection is *shared* between multiple threads to get maximum benefits of the resource.

Comment: You don't know MQ very well.  I have had queue managers with more than 10,000 client connections and the queue manager performs without issue.  Your 'large' is nothing.  Several years ago, I wrote a helper application called AQOL which defaults to 8 threads (1 connection per thread).  I have tested it with 100 threads without issue. I wrote about it here: http://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=1385  Note: I have over 20 years creating applications for MQ.  So, as I said, 1 connection per thread is a better solution but hey, if you want to build an overly complex system, I can't stop you.

Comment: Wow.. that seems to be pretty much authentic. Now I've another small question: if can I expect a connection to stay open (and valid) for several weeks/months? or I need to check its state before sending each message (if so, how to do that)?. Also, is creating session/producer/consumer/destination expensive? would be it good idea if I create them too frequently, like create them per message? or reuse them wherever possible?

Comment: There is no call to check if a connection is still valid/active. Just use the reconnect logic in MQ.  The most expensive call in MQ is the MQCONN/X (i.e. createQueueConnection() for JMS). Absolutely do NOT do 1 connection per message but rather reuse the connection/session.